# Dynamic storage of a binary file in C

Tags: c

```
Participant *readRankingList(const char *filename, int *length) {
    length = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    Participant *list;
    
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** open of %s failed ***\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    
    length = fread((void *)list, sizeof(Participant), LIST_LEN, fp);
    
    while (fread(list, sizeof(length), 1, fp) > 0) {
        list[i] = list;
        i++; 
    }
   
    free(list);
    fclose(fp);
    *length = i;
    return list;
}
```

I have a binary file, which I open in this part. Now I want to store it with a dynamic storage.

At the moment I get a

> Warning : assignment makes pointer from interfer without a cast

and an

> Error: incompatible types when assigning to type Participant from type struct Participant

Comment: use `malloc()` to assign memory first to `list`. Its a pointer, so no memory is initially allocated

Comment: `list[i]=list;`  --> this is wrong both syntactically and semantically.  Syntactically, `list` is a pointer to a `Participant` while `list[i]` is a `Participant`.  These two identifiers have different types and cannot be assigned.  Semantically, it makes no sense.     `free(list); ... return list;` --> this is another error.  you are returning a pointer to memory that you've already destroyed.

Comment: You never assign `list` a value. When you cast its value to `void *` to pass to `fread`, you are casting and passing a garbage value.

Answer (score 1):

You must allocate space for the structures with `malloc()` or `calloc()`. Seeking to the end of the file will give the number of entries. Reading the entries can be done in a single call to `fread`.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

Participant *readRankingList(const char *filename, int *length) {
    Participant *list;
    size_t count;
    
    // open the file
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** open of %s failed: %s ***\n", 
                filename, strerror(errno));
        *length = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    // get the number of structures
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    count = ftell(fp) / sizeof(Participant);
    if (count == 0) {
        fclose(fp);
        *length = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    // allocate memory for the array of Participants
    list = calloc(count, sizeof(*list));
    if (list == NULL) {
        fclose(fp);
        *length = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    // read the structures, update the length, return the pointer.
    rewind(fp);
    *length = fread(list, sizeof(Participant), count, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return list;
}
```